# How to stop using NVIDIA card on Centos

Tags: centos7, nvidia

I bought a machine many years ago that has an NVIDIA GPU installed. I no longer need the GPU and was going to give it to a colleague, but when I remove it, my system gets stuck booting at a step that gives no indication of why it is stuck, but it has to be the video card because when I put the card back it works again. So, how do I reconfigure Centos 7 to use the integrated video instead of the NVIDIA card? When I do a Google search I am finding post mostly about the opposite problem, so they aren't helpful. I haven't tried anything yet because honestly I don't know where to start. A solution to make the machine headless is probably fine since I access it remotely 99.9% of the time (although it might make it difficult to debug problems in the future, so I would prefer to have the option of a monitor).

Comment: How about `rpm -e $(rpm -qa | grep -i nvidia)`. I am sure there is a more correct syntax, but I gave up years ago trying to remember it.

Comment: That seems risky without more information. How do I know the onboard card will just work if I removed the nvidia drivers? Maybe then I get no video. Or it fails to boot at all.

Comment: You can always ssh into the box & reinstall. Alternatively, try blacklisting the modules & see what happens.

Comment: Unless it doesn't boot--As I mentioned, it doesn't boot if I remove the card. Also, I don't know what blacklisting modules means.

Comment: If you are not prepared to take even a minuscule risk, then perhaps Linux is not for you. Just stop the world & step off. As for blacklisting modules, just try a search.

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful. You give communities like this a good reputation. Also, I have used Unix for 30+ years, I'm just not an expert at video drivers on it since it rarely comes up. And having my machine fail to boot is not a minuscule risk. Instead I think I'll find someone who has more experience with this sort of thing and get a solution with no risk.